# Traverse Ajax Success JSON result in loop - CodeIgniter

Tags: jquery, ajax, codeigniter

I am making a call to the database using AJAX. But I am unable to traverse the resulted JSON in Jquery.

This is the result I am Getting:

```
[{"chatId":"13","senderId":"1"}
  ,{"chatId":"12","senderId":"1"}
  ,{"chatId":"11","senderId":"1"}]
```

Below is my AJAX:

```
    var otherId = $('#firstChat').html();
    var myId = $('#myId').html();
    $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: "chat/get_chat_thread",
        data: {otherId: otherId, myId: myId},
        success: function (ajaxresult) 
        {
            console.log(ajaxresult);
            // WHAT TO DO HERE??? TRIED MANY THINGS BUT DIDN'T WORKED
        }
    });
```

My chat/get_chat_thread is below:

```
public function get_chat_thread()
{
    if($data = $this->chat_model->get_chat_thread('1','2'))
    {
        print_r(json_encode($data));
    }
    else
    {
        echo false;
    }   
}
```

How to traverse it? Any help would be much appreciated. Plus, If I use

**return json_encode($data);** instead of  **print_r(json_encode($data));**. Then I get empty result.

Comment: what about `console.log($.parseJSON(strJsonTest));`?

Comment: Bro I am already getting result. My question is how do I traverse this result index wise? Means in loop. Thanks!

Comment: should i guess or what? - i mean this is basic understanding how `JS` works - nobody knows what you want to do here - since you use `jQuery` - take a look @http://api.jquery.com/jquery.each/ - maybe this helps ?

Comment: Let me apply this bro.

Comment: My each function was not working before because I was returning a printed json. But now each function worked with the answer @ourmandave posted.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't `return json_encode($data)`.

Try

```
return $this->output
        ->set_content_type('application/json')
        ->set_status_header(200)
        ->set_output(json_encode($data));
```

Comment: And what to do to traverse this json object array in AJAX success function?

Comment: Worked by using each function of jquery. :)

Comment: I knew someone would cover the js part. =)